# Elegant way to convert an array by subitems key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'XML' (length=3)
      'processer' => string 'XMLp' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'XML2' (length=3)
      'processer' => string 'XML2pr' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'CSV' (length=3)
      'processer' => string 'CSVp' (length=12)
```

Since I dont need all of this, I wasnt this array converted:

```
$a = array ('XML', 'XML2', 'CSV');
```

so get by 'name'. How to do this elegantly in php?

Comment: _Elegance_ is subjective. How do define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$source = array( 
    0 => array ( 
        'name' =>'A',
        'processer' => 'XMLf'),
    1 => array (
            'name' =>'B',
            'processer' => 'XMLp'),
    2 => array (
            'name' =>'C',
            'processer' => 'XMLp')
);

$output = array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value['name'];
}, $source);

print_r($output);
```

Comment: what is $v ?? can u explain i didnt get

Comment: The faster or slower it's another question :)

Comment: @Rinzler: It's an anonymous function, look at this: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#96564

Comment: @Jeroen: elegant and fast aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: $v - each element in array. function($v) {.. } - Callback function to run for each element in each array.

Comment: That's not "significantly slower". Your benchmark is wrong because you don't test multiple times for each method, you only test them in a defined order and the array is way to small for it to make a difference. What if you switch order of the tests? The first time I switched order I got the opposite result, hinting at the fact that the array may be in the CPU cache the second time around. Because the benchmark is wrong the result of it is meaningless. Also, do you really need this microoptimization?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't think of that - removed my benchmark.

Comment: I did some more benchmarks, switching order of the tests and using array_fill to fill $arr with a million records. It looks like the `foreach` method beats the `array_map` method with about half the time *on my machine* (34 vs 71 seconds for a million records). That's not "significantly slower" in most contexts. Also, I think the array_map method is cleaner! I've learnt some functional programming the last two years and it's a really nice paradigm!

Comment: Basically, it really depends on your definition of elegant, it's completely subjective (I personally find the loop to be easier to read)

Answer (score 3):

You could just loop over it, I don't think there's a much more elegant way:

```
$a = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $a[] = $value ['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $a) $new[] = $a['name'];
```

Comment: well I know this too, but I wanted more simplier version

Comment: Which part of this is not simple? The code is easily readable and is the #1 in terms of code length. Writing a function to retrieve data like in the top answer is overdoing and thus waste of time.

Comment: And as Jeroen stated, my method is way faster. Because, again, writing a function to retrieve data from array... It is ridiculous.

Comment: Andrius, functional programming is actually pretty elegant. I like `array_map` and friends, and I don't think it's ridiculous.

Comment: I am not saying functional programming is not elegant. I am saying: for this case there is no point to slow the program down :)